# android media codec Unable to instantiate a decoder for type 'video/mp4'

Tags: android, video, mp4, android-mediacodec

Working on implementing the mediamuxer class. It takes an inputs from the mediacodec class (one audio and one video). But throws an error when trying to encode for "video/mp4"

Code:

```
String mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
                .getMimeTypeFromExtension("mp4");
        codec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(mime);
```

Error:

```
Unable to instantiate a decoder for type 'video/mp4'
```

Notice the error is for decoder and the call is to create encoder.

I will probably figure this out in a minute, but it will be here for anyone else who runs into this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of fumbling around I found it documented, [Android recomended media formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations), but following [dbro](https://github.com/OnlyInAmerica/HWEncoderExperiments/blob/61cd18c7c602ae20ccc0ff0e02e82a1e3d5ea958/HWEncoderExperiments/src/main/java/net/openwatch/hwencoderexperiments/ChunkedAvcEncoder.java) and [fadden](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/)'s examples, the MediaMuxer works taking the following types of MediaEncoder inputs to create a elmetary H.264 stream and Mux it into an MP4 file:

```
private static final String VIDEO_MIME_TYPE = "video/avc";
private static final String AUDIO_MIME_TYPE = "audio/mp4a-latm";
```

Comment: Need to use exact string as mentioned in [Android Dev Support](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#createDecoderByType(java.lang.String)) . Like `"video/avc"` - H.264/AVC video